# Nested grouping based on parent field using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

This is a sample of the raw XML I'm working with:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
  <Rows>
    <Row Title="Animal" Parent="" />
    <Row Title="Mammal" Parent="Animal" />
    <Row Title="Lion" Parent="Mammal" />
    <Row Title="Plant" Parent="" />
    <Row Title="Elephant" Parent="Mammal" />
  </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

Using XSLT, how do I get the output to be a nested UL like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Animal
    <ul>
      <li>
        Mammal
        <ul>
          <li>Elephant</li>
          <li>Lion</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Plant</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>I'm only "okay" with XSLT and can only do simple sorting, and I know I can do this easily through JavaScript/jQuery, but I'd rather use XSLT for this.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row[@Parent = '']"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>

      <xsl:if test="../Row[@Parent = current()/@Title]">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../Row[@Parent = current()/@Title]"/>
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Animal<ul>
      <li>
        Mammal<ul>
          <li>Lion</li>
          <li>Elephant</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Plant</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

The "elegant" (and efficient!) solution here is to use a **key** to retrieve "related" records:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-parent" match="Row" use="@Parent" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not(string(@Parent))]"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
        <xsl:variable name="child-rows" select="key('row-by-parent', @Title)" />
        <xsl:if test="$child-rows">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$child-rows"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge.

This xsl gets an html document which is what I think you want. It's not formatted pretty though. The matching template starts the process searching for nodes with no parent. It then calls a template for that type. That template recursively calls itself to iterate the child types.

I used the command line app msxsl to test it. YMMV

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" version="1.0"
                >
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template name="CategoryTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="CategoryName"/>

    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='dsQueryResponse']/*[local-name()='Rows']/*[local-name()='Row' and @Parent=$CategoryName]">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>

          <!--recursively call template with category-->
          <xsl:call-template name="CategoryTemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="CategoryName" select="@Title"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='dsQueryResponse']/*[local-name()='Rows']">

    <xsl:variable name="CategoryName">
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:call-template name="CategoryTemplate">
          <xsl:with-param name="CategoryName" select="$CategoryName"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT has a [built-in recursion mechanism](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model) with the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction. There's no need to work so hard to replicate it.

Comment: This one has issues where tags aren't closed off in the right places. Tested using http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: Interesting that it runs in the msxsl command line app with tags that aren't closed

Comment: @michael.hor257k's solution seems far better than this one.